# Do airpods case's battery drain when it's left open and airpods are in use?

Tags: battery, airpods

I just joined this community. I hope this an appropriate question to ask here. If not, please let me know, if you know, where I should ask this.

I own a set of Apple Airpods Pro (2nd Gen? is there a 3rd Gen?). Sometimes when I'm using my Airpods I forget to close the case. I'm just wondering if leaving the case open while I'm using my AirPods drain the battery of the case? Does it matter whether I leave it open or close it?